# Visual Studio debugger launching application has different outcome from manually launching

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When launching a program from Visual Studio 2012 in debug mode (using the "Play" button), my application fails at a certain line of code. For the sake of being specific, the error I'm receiving is:

> Method Open threw an exception.  Could not create a service object instance, or could not get its IDispatch interface.

However, when I run the application by simply launching the EXE by clicking on the file name, I do not encounter this error.

Additionally interesting is the fact that I can add the following statement to my code (causing the debugger to attach AFTER launch) and I do not receive the exception I mentioned above.

```
if(!Debugger.IsAttached) {
    Debugger.Launch();
}
```

So, in short: When Visual Studio launches my program, there is SOMETHING different about the processes permissions / rights, app domain, or other factor that is changing its ability to operate "normally". I know that the parent process of my application when launched from Visual Studio is the **devenv.exe** process, could that have anything to do with it?

Some troubleshooting I've done:

- I have disabled the Visual Studio Hosting Process to eliminate that from being a potential issue.
- I've inspected the process in each different testing scenario listed above in Sys Internals' Process Explorer. I've compared permissions, session, user name the application was launched under, and many other things to attempt to find a reason why the application would function differently. All comparisons come up identical with the exception of the parent process (**explorer.exe** when launched manually and **devenv.exe** when launched through Visual Studio)

Any ideas?

#### Update:

I did another test and selected **Debug -> Start Without Debugging**, which DID NOT produce the error specified, but still launched the program with its parent process being **devenv.exe** which rules out that as being a potential issue. So its something to do with the debugger being attached right from the start of the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16696444/395718

Comment: This could be caused by the VS's debug hosting process. Try disabling hosting and running in the debugger again. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx) for instructions on disabling it.

Comment: Hi @Mikez , you have a good idea, however I've already done that (per my comments above). Any other ideas?