# Program doesn't work outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013, pinvoke

I use unmanaged dll with P/Invoke in this app, and I always tested it inside Visual Studio (with debug mode on x86 CPU because the dlls are only x86), and it works just fine. But when I just start the exe manually after some time (probably at the first operation with those dlls, but I don't know exactly) it says the exe has stopped working, and it starts checking for solution (I use Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, if that matters). I tried to add the dlls to the project as existing item, but that doesn't help. Also I know, that it's not because it can't find those dlls, cause if I delete them, it doesn't crash, just freeze without any error message. Shouldn't it work the same from Visual Studio as manually started?

There is also a weird bug when I run from Visual Studio: everything's work fine, but sometimes Visual Studio just suddenly stops debugging, as if the program were closed and the GUI of my app freezes, and I can only close it by closing Visual Studio (as I close it, the GUI disappears). Maybe it's a totally different problem, but it can be connected.

**Edit:**

Here's the project on github, if somebody could check it:
https://github.com/geiszla/CycriptGUI

**Some news:** If I run it with Ctrl+F5 it also crashes. What's the difference between F5 and Ctrl+F5, that can cause this problem?

Comment: do you need to register the DLL using regsvr32? have you also tried running the app in administrator mode outside of VS?

Comment: Add some logging to your application. Even a single try-catch around your main to output to the console the exception/stacktrace could probably help you a lot debug your stuff.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas It's a C library, not a COM library, so as I understand I don't need to register it.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I tried to put the updateTask into try-catch, but it didn't help (I think that part is the problem, cause I use the dlls there first, and if I remove the update task starting part it doesn't crash). (See code above)

Comment: I had a problem like this, and the reason it wasn't crashing when run under the debugger is that the offending code was within this `if` statement: `if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)`.  It's a long shot, but you might want to check whether you're deliberately running different code when attached to the debugger.

Comment: I deleted my answer ,useful link: [libimobiledevice-dotnet](https://github.com/chefvonaustralien/libimobiledevice-dotnet)

Comment: Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16696444/395718

Comment: Please don't ask the question in an offsite link.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for every help, my problem was solved: I called an unmanaged function with only 2 parameters, while it had 3. However I still don't understand why it worked with debugging mode, and not without debugging.

Comment: undefined behaviour is a b**tch, be happy that it failed immediatly, not 6 months from now in production at midnight for your biggest customer

Answer (score 1):

Searched all over Google with no real simple answers. Here it is folks(at least it worked for me and is simple):

When you run the console app in Visual Studio, look at the output window at the bottom, get the location of the ..\bin\Debug\*.exe

Copy the *.exe and the *.config to your desired folder, run it, it should work the same way in Visual Studio.